# Can't login to Archiva via LDAP with "Could not find object" error

Tags: authentication, ldap

We upgraded to Apache Archiva 2.1.1 and successfully configured LDAP, so that "Ldap connection verified." appears in Redback Runtime Configuration. My user credentials are also recognized, as there is a distinct message when the username/password combinations is incorrect.

The failure message on login with the correct credentials is "
**Could not find object. Type 'org.apache.archiva.redback.users.jdo.JdoUser'. Id: 'X'.]** where X is the user uid. I already checked that all `ldap.config.mapper.attribute` values exist for my username.

Is it necessary to use groups? I didn't use groups at first but now created a user group and added the group base dn but the "LDAP/Roles Mapping" tab in Redback Runtime Configuration does not show me any LDAP groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: In Archiva, under the menu option "Redback Runtime Configuration" you need to drag the "LDAP User Manager" from the "Available User Managers" area to the "UserManager(s) chosen". Even though it all looks grayed out these are actual interactive components :)